# sometime website get stuck on proceed to checkout and Add to cart in magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: database, magento-1

I am having issue on my website after updating magento version 1.9.3.3 from 1.9.2.4. sometime `proceed to checkout`and `add to cart` option does not work. and my admin is also running slow. When I Select `NO - Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout`. Everything works perfectly. I do not know what is the issue related to form key validation. can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if `Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout - yes`. Need to confirm `echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')` is passed in your form.

If the formkey is not passed in your form. it will not work.

Please check your inspect element and check http-header and confirm formkey is passed in your form.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue when I enabled Form Key Validation and did NOT clear Magento cache and browser cache, It would get suck at Payment methods. I used fresh browser with cleared cache, checkout started to work properly.

Also, Rama made a good point, if what I have mentioned doesn't work. Then you need to  set form-key in checkout page. Possibly you are using non-generic Magento checkout.